# React hooks: accessing setter during cleanup call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to fully understand the React hooks life cycle, more precisely how to minimize re-rendering. I created a simple component which displays the current time. The first code displayed here works just fine:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const timeFormat = ["en-US", { hour12: false }]
const period = 1000

export default function ClockText() {
    let [time, setTime] = useState(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(...timeFormat))

    useEffect(() => {
        let interval = setInterval(
            () => setTime(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(...timeFormat)),
            period)
        console.log("Set interval id=" + interval)
        return () => {
            console.log("Clear interval id=" + interval)
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
    }, [])

    return ( <div> {time} </div> )
}
```

The `useEffect` never gets updated, `interval` doesn't change during the component's life cycle, this component unmount cleanly, all is fine.

Now I'm trying to see how to write more complex cleanup calls, where I would need to access more data etc. without adding elements in the `useEffect` dependency list (so as to not enter in a game of trying to avoid re-rendering).

I tried the following changes:

```
export default function ClockText() {
    let [time, setTime] = useState(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(...timeFormat))
    // New state:
    //
    let [, setRefreshInterval] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        let interval = setInterval(
            () => setTime(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(...timeFormat)),
            period)
        console.log("Set interval id=" + interval)
        setRefreshInterval(interval)

        // Modified cleanup:
        //
        return (() => {
            setRefreshInterval(previousRefreshInterval => {
                console.log("Clear interval id=" + previousRefreshInterval)
                clearInterval(previousRefreshInterval)   
                return null 
            })            
        })
    }, [])
    // ...
```

This fails. I was expecting to enter `setRefreshInterval` and execute its content, but this never happens. Placing a debugger, I see that this function still exists, we enter it, but never execute the code (I get lost in React's guts by then).

So are the setter functions lost by that time? Any reference which would explain this?

Comment: Why do you use the `setRefreshInterval()` as a state?

Comment: This is to illustrate more complex cases later on, where you create other type of async event source (sockets etc...) and need to have them as being part of your component's state.
This is just an exercise, it is obviously not meant to make any sense in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. React does not update state in sync way but plans updating
2. Your cleanup happens when component is going to be removed

So line `setRefreshInterval(...` is executed(you may validate that by placing breakpoint), but update planned is silently dropped later(since it does not make any sense for setter to update state - it knows nothing that you're expecting it because of side-effect)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Right, I forgot that the setter will execute later on... great, thank you!